# ¿Cómo obtener el valor devuelto por mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas tardes soy nuevo en esto.

tengo una consulta sql para encontrar la distancia mas cercana teniendo en cuenta una latitud y longitud

```
SELECT id, (((acos(sin((4.127877*pi()/180)) * sin((lat*pi()/180)) + cos((4.127877*pi()/180)) * cos((lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((-73.618126- lon) * pi()/180)))) * 180/pi()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) as distance FROM personas HAVING distance <= 50 LIMIT 1
```

la consulta funciona y me arroja este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el php lo tengo asi para obtener el id de la persona

```
$cercano=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, (((acos(sin((4.127877*pi()/180)) * sin((lat*pi()/180)) + cos((4.127877*pi()/180)) * cos((lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((-73.618126- lon) * pi()/180)))) * 180/pi()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) as distance FROM personas HAVING distance <= 5 LIMIT 1" );

$cercan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cercano);
$cerca = implode($cercan[0]);
```

pero no imprime nada. En mi poco conocimiento arriba la consulta en SQL arroja dos valores el id y distance. Necesito obtener solo el id.

les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: La función [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) requiere dos parámetros: 1. Cadena para unir los elementos del arreglo. 2. El arreglo a unir. Nunca lo he probado con arreglos asociativos y no sé si funcione; en todo caso, puedes usar [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values) para enviar solo los valores o usar `fetch_row()` en lugar de `fetch_assoc()` para obtener un arreglo numérico al leer la consulta.

Comment: Si usas `mysqli_fetch_assoc` entonces deberías poder acceder a los valores de la consulta vía la clave del valor que existe en el array, algo como `$array["clave"]`

Comment: Triby muchas gracias me funciono asi

$cercan = mysqli_fetch_row($cercano);
$cerca = $cercan[0];

me salvo de una noche de trasnocho :D

Answer (score 0):

El código que llevas va bien encaminado, solo es cuestión de observar [la forma en la que entrega los resultados el método `mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Entonces como la salida que entrega es un array de *clave => valor*, ejemplo:

```
Array
(
    [clave1] => valor1
    [clave2] => valor2
)
```

Así que para acceder a los valores que recuperas debería ser así:

```
$cercano = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, 
                                   (((acos(sin((4.127877*pi()/180)) * sin((lat*pi()/180)) + cos((4.127877*pi()/180)) * cos((lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((-73.618126- lon) * pi()/180)))) * 180/pi()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) as distance 
                             FROM personas 
                             HAVING distance <= 5 LIMIT 1" );

$cercan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cercano);

$id = $cercan["id"];
$distance = $cercan["distance"];
```

*Indicando el nombre de la clave asociada a un valor y no de forma directa el índice que señale la posición del valor*